# Recommended Damson Recipe?

Tags: wine, recipe, country-wine

has anyone got any tried and approved recipe's for a wine or infusion that uses damsons? I've just discovered a free source whilst foraging yesterday.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A recipe for damson (sweet) wine from C.J.J. Berry - First Steps in Winemaking, I have not made this wine, but the ones I have made were excellent.

1.75Kg Damsons;
0.25kg barley (crushed);
1.75Kg Sugar;
4.5l   Water;
Pectic Enzyme;
Yeast and Yeast Nutrient.

Stone and cut up fruit, place damsons and barley in a pan and pour over boiling water, cover and leave for 4 days; add pectin when cool, stir daily.
Strain into fermenter and add yeast (preferably Burgundy wine yeast) and yeast nutrient. Rack when it drops clear. Only bottle when fermentation is complete.

When I made the plum wine to a similar recipe I couldn't be bothered waiting for the fruit to sit for 4 days, so I froze the stoned and diced fruit; to burst the cell walls and release the sugar and flavour. Then added boiling water to the frozen block, and put on the hob for 5 min. Then when it cooled to 35C added the pectin, left it over night and strained into  fermenter and added yeast. This seemed to get most of the essence out of the fruit without the wait.